# Force security constraint managed 403 error when hitting restricted page with h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, navigation, security-constraint

I have a Jakarta EE10 application running in Wildfly 30.
In the web.xml I define a security-constraint:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>AccountManager</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/pages/person/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>AccountManager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

In my software I made a `<h:commandLink>` with an action that results in `/pages/person/change.xhtml`. A user who has no role `AccountManager` can get that page. In the url-bar in the browser is the previous url shown, strange, but that is normal with Jakarta Faces. How can I prevent this?

I should make the `<h:commandLink>` only rendered for an `AccountManager`, but I hoped that the security-constraint would catch that link.

If the user enters the url for `pagers/person/change.xhtml` in the url-bar, he receives a decent 403 (this is how it should work).

Comment: Just use GET instead of POST to navigate. See abovelinked duplicate. JSF 2.0+ has been around for long already to make it possible. No need to stick to JSF 1.x minded practices.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, that was clear enough for me.